# Set child node as root node using jackson

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, objectmapper

The question is quite simple:
From this:

```
{
"categoryId":"some_id",    
"properties": {
            "id": "braja_de_nana",
            "displayName": "test",
            "longDescription": "<p>TESTE</p>",
            "active": true,
            "attributes": [
                {
                  "name": "made",
                  "value": "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_VALUE",
                  "property": "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_NAME"
                },
                {
                  "name": "made",
                  "value": "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_VALUE_2",
                  "property": "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_NAME_2"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This should be the result:

It means that **every array element of 'attributes'** should become a **new root node**.

set 'property' from 'attributes' **as the object node name**.
set 'value' from 'attributes' **as the object node value.**

```
{
    "categoryId":"some_id",
    "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_VALUE":"THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_NAME",
    "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_NAME_2":"THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_VALUE_2"
    "properties": {
                "id": "braja_de_nana",
                "displayName": "test",
                "longDescription": "<p>TESTE</p>",
                "active": true
            }
    }
```

This is a challenge for me.
I can set new nodes into the root node.
Already got a map from 'attributes' and then tried to iterate them with forEach in order to put the result into one single node, but instead as shown I have to take the 'property' set it to the object name´s key, then get the value and set to its value.

**UPDATE 2**

```
 @Override
    public String toOccProductDTO(ProcessProductDTO processProductDTO) throws JsonProcessingException {
        OccProductDTO occProductDTO = OccProductDTO.builder()
                .categoryId(processProductDTO.getCategoryId())
                .productType(processProductDTO.getCategoryId())
                .properties(toOccProductPropertiesDTO(processProductDTO))
                .build();
        toOccProductPropertiesDTO(processProductDTO);
        String tree = mapper.writeValueAsString(occProductDTO);

        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(tree);
        JsonNode attributesNodeArray = ((ObjectNode) root.get("properties"))
                .remove("p_specs");

        Iterator<JsonNode> arrayNodes = attributesNodeArray.iterator();

        while (arrayNodes.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode node = arrayNodes.next();
            root = ((ObjectNode)root).set(node.get("value").asText(), node.get("property"));
        }

        System.out.println(root.toPrettyString());
        return null;
    }
```

I got an: arrayNodes: Collection$EmptyIterator at that line.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In your second update you have `.remove("p_specs")` instead of `.remove("attributes")`. The node `"p_specs"` is missing in your input JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it was more complex than expected.
It turns out that I solved the problem with Oboe´s help. Although he missed some points through his implementation plus some changes I could achieve the goal.

```
         //Converts the parsed objects into Json String
                String tree = mapper.writeValueAsString(occProductDTO);
        
                //Reads the json string to JsonNode in order to manipulate it
                JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(tree);

//Sets the chosen node where the new nodes should be created
 JsonNode properties = root.path("properties");
        
//maps the two attribs needed
                Map<String, String> attribs = processProductDTO.getProductDTO().getAttributes().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(AttributeDTO::getProperty, AttributeDTO::getValue));
    
    //Converts each attrib into a String list
                List<String> props = attribs.entrySet().stream()
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, String>::getValue).reversed())
                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                List<String> names = attribs.entrySet()
                        .stream()                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String,String>::getValue).reversed())
                        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
    //iterates over the two lists adding the attribs to their corresponding position
                Iterator<String> arrayNodes = props.listIterator();
                Iterator<String> arrayNodes2 = names.listIterator();
        
                while (arrayNodes.hasNext()) {
                    String node = arrayNodes.next();
                    String node2 = arrayNodes2.next();
                    properties = ((ObjectNode)properties).put(node, node2);
                }
        
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(root);
            }
```

In the end, instead of passing a java object via @Post, I´m passing a json String by using "consumes = application/json, produces = "application.json"

That´s it!

Maybe it could be achieved and better implemented with java 8 stream, but for now it works.
Suggestion to improve the code are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to the attributes to the root node, you can remove that node and add its fields to the root.

The `"attributes"` node is an array with length 1, so you have to get the first element of the array to get the attribute fields.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);

JsonNode attributesNodeArray = ((ObjectNode) root.get("properties"))
        .remove("attributes");

JsonNode attributesNode = attributesNodeArray.get(0);

Iterator<String> fieldNames = attributesNode.fieldNames();

while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
    String name = fieldNames.next();
    root = ((ObjectNode)root).set(name, attributesNode.get(name));
}

System.out.println(root.toPrettyString());
```

Output:

```
{
  "categoryId" : "some_id",
  "properties" : {
    "id" : "braja_de_nana",
    "displayName" : "test",
    "longDescription" : "<p>TESTE</p>",
    "active" : true
  },
  "name" : "made",
  "value" : "some value",
  "property" : "some_value"
}
```

**UPDATE**

For the updated question, you can do the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);

JsonNode attributesNodeArray = ((ObjectNode) root.get("properties"))
        .remove("attributes");

Iterator<JsonNode> arrayNodes = attributesNodeArray.iterator();

while (arrayNodes.hasNext()) {
    JsonNode node = arrayNodes.next();
    root = ((ObjectNode)root).set(node.get("value").asText(), node.get("property"));
}

System.out.println(root.toPrettyString());
```

Output:

```
{
  "categoryId" : "some_id",
  "properties" : {
    "id" : "braja_de_nana",
    "displayName" : "test",
    "longDescription" : "<p>TESTE</p>",
    "active" : true
  },
  "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_VALUE" : "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_NAME",
  "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_VALUE_2" : "THIS_BECOMES_A_NODE_NAME_2"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is almost the result I need. But there are two points: 1. 'attributes' can have N objects with those three fields (name, value and property) 2. after removing I have to set 'property' as objects node name and 'value' as its value. Is it possible to do that in java? Thank you in advance

Comment: while debbuging your code, I get the expected result if I have only one object in 'attributes'. Could I use Json array or something like that?

Comment: Update your question with the same JSON input and output you need (with more than one attribute), and I'll try to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated now. Hope that it´s clearer now.

Comment: attributesNode always gets null no mather what I pass as param

Comment: In the answer, I use the JSON posted in the question (a simple copy/paste), and the output is what I get when running the code (which is equal to the desired JSON).

Comment: I´m gonna post my whole method because it´s still not working for me.

Comment: 'p_specs' is a list of attributes that get parsed before handling the json.

Comment: Till now, I just had to parse into JSON using 'writeValueAsString' because my objects were static so to speak. However in the last minute they said that 'attributes' (input) should become a root node (p_specs in the output to the other micro service). The problem is I can´t create another fields for this new 'attributes' because its size is random. It could be 1 or N attributes so I´m not able to forsee how many fields in my java object I ´m gonna need. Therefore I decided for this approach in Json.

Comment: it seems that the .remove() is erasing the whole array and its objects. Not only the node.